# Remotely place a file on a windows folder

Tags: php, windows

I need to take a file and move it to a windows machine on a specific folder where it is then to be printed automatically.  How would I accomplish something like this?  Is it possible with PHP?

Comment: Do you have control over the client machine?

Answer (score 0):

Have the user [upload the file using a POST form](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), then use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to put it into the right folder.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with PHP. You can upload the file using POST (there are many examples online), and then use - for example -  [move_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to move the file to the appropriate location.

However, you will need to make sure the folder has the appropriate permissions to allow the web server to move files into it.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible with PHP. 
but it's also possible with simple `copy` console command

To have another answer, you need to provide much more information.